# How to properly implement iAd with swift?

Tags: swift, iad

I am implementing ads into my new app and I have banner ads and occasional interstitial ads. Is it okay to handle them by setting them to automatic and setting `self.candisplaybannerads = true` in the `viewDidLoad`? Will this handle when there is no ad to display? I do not want my app to be rejected because I forgot to add a couple of methods to handle it. My understanding is that this way Apple handles them for you and no need for customization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some working code for you that just worked for me. This does not even need `self.candisplaybannerads = true` as I had some issues with that. This is just for the small ads. The ad automatically changes the size according to the screen size and is located at the bottom of the screen.

```
import iAd

class viewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var AdBanner = ADBannerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        /* Ad Banner Settings */

        AdBanner = ADBannerView()
        AdBanner.frame = CGRectZero
        AdBanner.delegate = self
        self.AdBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-self.AdBanner.frame.size.height, self.AdBanner.frame.size.width, self.AdBanner.frame.size.height)
        AdBanner.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.view .addSubview(AdBanner)

}

/* All iAd Functions */

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
/* whatever you need */
    return true
}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
/* whatever you need */
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    AdBanner.hidden = false
}


func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("Error Loading Ad")
/* whatever you need */
    AdBanner.hidden = true
}
func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
/* whatever you need */
}
```